# How to add Pycharm Community Edition to path

Tags: command-line

I want to add Pycharm to my path so that I may launch it from the command line from any directory in the same way that atom can launch from terminal if I type atom.

I have already tried charm, pycharm-community, and believe instead I need to add this to my path?

Also, how would I do this for other programs in general as well.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How did you install pycharm? If you used the snap package it should already be in your path.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to find where is located this software:

```
find / -name charm -type f 2>/dev/null
```

and you will have output like this:

```
/path/to/charm
```

then you can add this in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to
```

then logout and login again or exec in current shell

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Easy Way

Download the [Jetbrains Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) for Linux.  This app will keep all the Jetbrains tools organized (not just PyCharm), and allows you to install them anywhere with easy access to other "Community Editions."  You can set the Startup script and Startup Directory from the toolbox itself.  Make sure you meet the Linux System Requirements:

> 64-bit x86, glibc 2.17 (Ubuntu 18.04 or newer).
>
> Toolbox App is packaged in AppImage and requires FUSE to run. See AppImage Wiki for details.
>
> The following packages must be present:
>
> libfuse2 libxi6 libxrender1 libxtst6 mesa-utils libfontconfig libgtk-3-bin tar

Pulled From Quote:

- [AppImage Homepage](https://appimage.org/)
- [AppImage: FUSE](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE)